# SSIS : Auditing SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating SSIS 2016 package which contains multiple data flow tasks. Each data flow task contains oledb source and oledb destination.

I have created two Execute SQL tasks one in the end and the other at the end of the entire process. I have named it Audit start and Audit End respectively.

I am trying to capture the following information in the audit table

```
PackageName, StartTime, EndTime, NumberOfRecords, MaxFinancialInstanceId
```

The audit start will insert the `PackageName` and `startime` while audit end will call the update stored procedure to add `EndTime, NumberOfRecords, MaxFinancialInstanceId`

I am aware that most of this information can be obtained by querying SSIDB

For e.g

```
SELECT execution_id,
              package_name,
              source_component_name,
              destination_component_name,
              rows_sent,
              created_time
FROM [internal].[execution_data_statistics]
```

But in my case I would have some additional column information captured as well. Please note that my database and package would reside on different servers.

Is it wise to do the way I am manually doing or connect to the package server and get the information.

If the manual way is recommended then how do I capture the total records transmitted ?

Comment: Use Row Count - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/row-count-transformation

Comment: I know the  rowcount can be used for each dataflow. I am looking at capturing rowcount for all dataflows and storing only the total. How do I do that. As I mentioned in my post , I have multiple dataflows

Comment: If I set the rowcount for each dataflow, will it get updated or will it overwrite the variable

Comment: Not sure, if it does get over written then have multiple row count variables and sum the total of all to store

Comment: merge all the dataflows using union all transformation and get the rowcount using rowcount transformation. if the columns are different, identify a string or integer column for pseudo union all and get the rowcount

Comment: Any example to share ?