# SSIS Audit Logs DB

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have several SSIS packages created to transfer data and process a SQL merge in tables that then feed some views.  To assist in resolving errors going forward I am trying to build an audit database or audit table within source or destination database that records process\package name, start time, if successful and a count of rows in destination table at start and finish of process.  I found this Stackoverflow article that is similar but there was no answer given

[SSIS : Auditing SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285281/ssis-auditing-ssis-package)

I found this youtube article and followed it to attempt the first stage which was count the rows of destination table.  The first Execute SQL Task succeeds with a green tick and the task for the two Execute SQL Tasks completes with no errors are shown but nothing is written in the audit table and the second Execute SQL Task has no green tick
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c56QtG-NPJw

This is my Control Flow to Test setting up the Audit

[image]

The first SQL Task has a "Single Row" Results set with SQL Statement.  I am casting as varchar 50 to ensure I was following the video tutorial and table column is varchar 50

SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS Counted FROM dbo.MyTable

and second SQL Task has the parameter mapping to get the value from first SQL task and a SQL statement of where "Counted" is the column name in table

INSERT INTO dbo.table_AUDIT (Counted)
VALUES (?);

Why is this not working please?

Comment: You working with SQL Server as source and destination?

Comment: Also, screenshots of your second sql task. Show off the parameter mapping tab. When you run the package, you state nothing is written in your second Execute SQL Task. If it is getting the green tick/success, then the statement executed without error and some table somewhere has the inserted value.

Comment: @billinkc yes both source and destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to take a different approach to achieve the same goal:

Let's assume you created a audit_log table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_audit](
    audit_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    PackageName VARCHAR(50),
    TaskName VARCHAR(50),
    RowsCounted INT,
    insert_date DATETIME
)
```

You can build such an ETL Package:

[image: SER]

Let's define step by step:

First SQL Task: Indicates that Package started!

Make a direct Input (No parameter mapping tab, no results):

[image: EXpre]

Select sqlstatementsource from property menu:

[image: SER]

and paste this code into expression:

```
"insert into [dbo].[tbl_audit] values('"+ @[System::PackageName] +"','PackageStarted',0,GETDATE())"
```

Second DFT Task:

[image: DFT]

You need to create a variable to use in RowCount Transformation:

[image: RRH]

[image]

Third SQL Task:

The same steps in 1st stage:

[image: SERY]

This time you need to paste this code:

```
"insert into [dbo].[tbl_audit] values('"+ @[System::PackageName] +"','"+ @[System::TaskName] +"',"+ (DT_STR,12,1252)@[User::UCount] +",GETDATE())"
```

After you execute package and check the tbl_audit log table:

[image]

Comment: @AJF I added a detailed explanation for you.

Comment: thanks for suggestion and additional information.  This has helped as I found I had a parameter wrong and I have made some progress.  However, I am trying to do one part you suggest and use an expression with a select statement for the value of a variable but it doesn't seem to work.  It so far only works if I have a SQL task to do the select before the Insert SQL task and pass the value of the select as a parameter